# Is there a way to display a file via the Realtime API without someone auth'ing into Google?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

The permissions are set to public. But still if someone hasn't auth'd, the collaborative string doesn't show up for them. If they auth and reload the page, then they can view the doc.

Answer (score 0):

No, currently only authorized users can access Realtime documents.  Do you have a use case for public access?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Cheryl.

The use case would be for a large group who want to work together on a document inside of our application, same as they would collaborate on a Google Doc that is shared with anyone with the link. That's not possible, right?

By the way - thank you SO much for responding. Very cool!